Unwanted looping reports when I execute my SQL Server stored procedure instead of just one result
I am getting a continuous looping report rather than just one report when I execute my stored procedure. I don't know why this is happening.
Here is the code I am working with:
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSalariesAboveAverge 
AS
BEGIN
    ---SQL Statements Here--------------------
    SELECT
        salary, 
        COUNT(*) AS salary_group, 
        last_name
    FROM
        employee
    GROUP BY
        salary, last_name
    HAVING
        salary >= 23000
    ORDER BY
        salary DESC;
END

EXEC GetSalariesAboveAverge

And here is the result:

Error message:

Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetSalariesAboveAverge, Line 12
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).


You need to put a GO (batch separator) between your procedure code and EXEC spProcedure, otherwise execution becomes part of the procedure itself

Also, since you're really filtering on a column directly (not on an aggregate of a column), you should use WHERE instead of HAVING ....

Thanks friends. The suggestions were spot on!
